# Bot wrongly handle messages

Tags: python, telethon

I have little problem with writing my bot, I'm trying to send message only inside my bot, but my client handle any messages in any chats.

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, events
import socks
api_id = 'my_id'
api_hash = 'my_hash'
client = TelegramClient('name', api_id, api_hash, proxy=###).start(bot_token='bot_token') 

@client.on(events.NewMessage(pattern='/start'))
async def send_welcome(event):
    await event.reply('How re you doing')

@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def echo_all(event):
    await event.reply(event.text)

client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to had `func=lambda e: e.is_private` into `events.NewMessage()` so the handler will only catch messages from private conversations *(that's what you defined as "messages only inside your bot")*.

It will look like this:

```
@events.register(events.NewMessage(func=lambda e: e.is_private))
async def handler(event):
    ...
```